# Rmate for Sublime connecting and opening files, but not saving properly

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm on a laptop running Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.3.  I'm trying to connect to my RaspberryPi 3 via `ssh -R 52698:127.0.0.1:52698 username@192.168.0.2`, which I have aliased to `pilogin`.

After I log into the Pi, I leave the terminal open, open Sublime on the laptop, and go back to the terminal and type `rmate notes.txt`.  This opens `notes.txt` on the laptop, in Sublime.  In Sublime I see the changes I last made in the file using the preceding method.

However, if I go back to the terminal to the Pi and `cat notes.txt`, the last changes I made in Sublime are not visible.  At the top of my Sublime window on the laptop, it says `/tmp/raspberrypi-gkgq9l/notes.txt - Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)`.

I cd to the `/tmp/` directory and see the `/raspberrypi-gkg9l/` directory, and a file called `Sublime Text.2f0d11a6db9676ced66dac848f4de26a.sock`

Sublime has usually been working with `rmate` just fine, but this is new, and that's as far as I can figure to troubleshoot it, I have no idea where to look next.  Haven't found this problem in the forums yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. When you first log in to the Pi and open `notes.txt` using `rmate`, then view its contents in the terminal *without making any changes*, are the contents the same or different? Then, if you make changes in Sublime *and save them*, then `cat` the contents in the terminal, are they the same or different? Basically, is the issue that your saved changes aren't being reflected in the terminal?

Comment: In the meantime, here's something to try: quit Sublime and the `ssh` session. Go to `/tmp` and delete the subdirectory like so: `rm -rf raspberrypi-gkg9l`. Then, reopen Sublime and the `ssh` session and try `rmate notes.txt` again. Did that fix the problem?

Comment: Yea, the issue is that Sublime is saving to a tmp directory, then opening from it instead of the ssh connection.  I deleted the raspberrypi and ssh folders in the /tmp directory, started over, and the edited notes.txt came up in a new /tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

`rmate` apparently does not save to the remote file location until the file is closed in sublime, not just saved.  I followed MattDMo's advice and went through the connect, open, save, close & exit process and watched the `tmp` directories being made and removed.  Once the file is closed in sublime, it saves the file in the `tmp` directory to the remote file.